# What killed the creature chasing Edwin in Predators?

Tags: predator-series, predators-2010

In the movie [*Predators*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1424381/), Edwin (played by [Topher Grace](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0333410/)) is used as bait to draw out a creature, which was later revealed to be something also brought to the planet in a container as prey. Isabelle fires a shot and it looks like she was able to kill it.

Below, the creature is dead from a fatal wound.

[image: The creature killed.]

As it turns out, after examining a bullet hole in a tree, Isabelle says she actually missed.

[image: Isabelle admitting she missed.]

What exactly killed the creature then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's never clearly spelled out in the movie, but most likely, the [so-called river ghost alien](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/River_Ghost_Alien) was killed by <strike>Morpheus</strike> [Ronald Noland](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Noland), who was hanging around at the time, and revealed himself to the group right after.

Comment: He seems like the only likely candidate. But it certainly is weird since he ultimately wanted all the other survivors dead anyway.

Comment: @sunpech - not quite. He didn't want them dead per se - he wanted **their equipment**. Having them dead was merely the easiest way to arrive at that goal. And having them trust him after just saving one of them let him lure them all in to his house to be killed during sleep.

Comment: Why kill them when they're all exposed and ready for a fight and a hike away from his lair/hide? Better to 'save them' first then he can simply let them carry all the desired gear back to his place, then do them. BTW, I wonder what he eats??

Comment: @Morgan - livers, fava beans and cianti.

Comment: @DVK - Ah yes, comfort food.