# What was the creature that chased Edwin in Predators?

Tags: predator-series, predators-2010

When they use Edwin (Topher Grace) as bait in the movie *Predators* what was the creature that chased him? Does it appear anywhere else in the series or was it just a random critter they made up for this movie?

[image: screenshot of killed creature]

Picture source: [What killed the creature chasing Edwin in Predators?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25010/what-killed-the-creature-chasing-edwin-in-predators)

Comment: [Predator](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093773/) and [Predators](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1424381/) are 2 different movies.

Comment: I know that, Predators is the new one. Predator is the original movie with Arnold Schwarzenegger. I really don't see how that comment was relevant.

Comment: Ah, I see it was edited to be corrected, didn't know I made that mistake. My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other types of ETs do appear in the fictional reality that the Xenomorphs and Predators inhabit. One such alien is the giant that appears in Prometheus, which was a ET that was covered in a few of the novels as well. Other examples do occur in conversations, like the marines asking if their mission was another bug hunt in Aliens.

From what I could find regarding the new ET with wiki and interviews, it was new to the franchise, meant to be an example of another ET the Predators capture to release on the planet and hunt. This presumably is one of the other things being dropped that Noland (Lawrence Fishburne) refers to when he is telling the other humans about the behavior the Predators and the activities of the planet they find them selves on. One can safely assume that if Predators intend to hunt this new ET, this new ET can be considered a hunter and a killer on whatever planet it has been snatched from and should be considered dangerous.

While we may have not seen the ET in any previous film in the two franchises, there may be a Predators sequel in which there is another opportunity to encounter the tall, sinewy cockroach ET.